# MacBook EFI Firmware Update Dialog Always Reappears

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, firmware

After performing software update on my MacBook (late 2008) I am greeted with a dialog saying:

> Your computer's firmware is up-to-date with version 1.4 of the MacBook EFI Firmware Update.

The problem being that everytime I boot this dialog appears. I've tried to re-install the firmware update but it says that it is not needed.

I suspect it might either be bootcamp or that I had the macbook plugged into my macbook air's power adapter during the update. But that is pure speculation. I'd deeply appreciate any ideas for a fix or workaround.

This is on OS X 10.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that didn't take long. I found that in the System Preferences > Account > Login Items it is possible to uncheck the update program which was running automatically. Not sure why it got stuck but it's a workaround.